# Rubyのgemでxmindocがインストールできない【WindowsXP】

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

## xmindocのインストールができない

以下の記事をみてxmindocをインストールしようと思いましたができません。
http://qiita.com/sky_y/items/b92e9ce4b941545c8af5

行なった作業と結果を順にそのまま記録しておきます。
環境はWindowsXP SP3です。
XMind、Pandocはインストール済みです。

## Rubyのインストール

### 2.3.0はXPで動作しない

最初に投稿時点で最新の2.3.0をインストールしました。
しかし、WindowsXPでは動作しませんでした。

コマンドプロンプトを起動してコマンドを打つと「プロシージャエントリポイント _gmtime64_s がダイナミックリンクライブラリ msvcrt.dllから見つかりませんでした」というダイアログボックスが表示されて動作しませんでした。
ttp://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9069536.html

アンインストールしました。

### 1.9.3

Rubyは1.9.3をインストールしました。
ttp://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p551.exe

その後、コマンドプロンプトでxmindocをインストールしようとしましたが失敗しました。

```
>gem install xmindoc
```

---

```
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]

C:\>gem install xmindoc
Fetching: mini_portile2-2.0.0.rc2.gem (100%)
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.7.2-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Nokogiri is built with the packaged libraries: libxml2-2.9.2, libxslt-1.1.28, zl
ib-1.2.8, libiconv-1.14.
Fetching: zipruby-0.3.6.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing xmindoc:
        The 'zipruby' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'ttp://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'ttp://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

## DevKitのインストール

以下の記事によると「DevKit」なるものが必要らしいです。
ttp://yohshiy.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-240.html

記事のとおりに従い、インストールできました。

### 手順

1. 「DevKit」の入手
   For use with Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3:
   DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe（約22MB）
   ttp://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe
2. 上記の自己解凍exeを解凍
3. 「devkit」フォルダを作成して解凍したファイルを配置
4. コマンドプロンプトを起動し「devkit」フォルダに移動
5. 以下のコマンドを叩く

---

```
C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.9.3 at C:/Ruby193

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby193'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'
```

---

### gemのバージョン確認

```
>gem -v
1.8.29
```

### インストール失敗

再びコマンドプロンプトでxmindocをインストールしようとしましたが失敗しました。
以降、ずっとこのエラーが出てきて解決できません。

```
>gem install xmindoc

C:\root\downloads\devkit>gem install xmindoc
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing xmindoc:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for zlib.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0
.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0.3.6/ext/gem_make
.out
```

## ライブラリのインストール

以下の記事によると「RubyGemsを利用するときに必須となるzlibとOpenSSLのライブラリ」とあるのでライブラリを用意します。
ttp://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fcoding/articles/ruby191/ruby191a.html

### zlib

1. ファイルをダウンロード
   ttp://jarp.does.notwork.org/win32/zlib-1.1.4-1-mswin32.zip
2. 解凍後「bin/zlib.dll」ファイルを「C:/Ruby193/bin」へコピー

なお「C:/Ruby193/bin」には既に「zlib1.dll」というファイルがありました。

### OpenSSL

記事によると以下のファイルが必要らしいです。

- libeay32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

しかし「C:/Ruby193/bin」には既に同名のファイルがありました。
なので何もしませんでした。

その後、再びコマンドプロンプトでxmindocをインストールしようとしましたが失敗しました。

```
>gem install xmindoc
（前のと同じエラー）
```

## mkmf.log

エラーログにあった「mkmf.log」ファイルをみつけて中をみてみました。
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0.3.6/ext/mkmf.log

```
have_header: checking for zlib.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.   -march=i486   -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <zlib.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

よくわかりませんが「zlib.h」があやしい気がします。
「conftest.c:5:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory」をみると「zlib.h」ファイルが見つからないと言っているようです。

おそらくgcc -IC コマンドから察するに、以下のフォルダからヘッダファイルを検索しているはずです。
なので「zlib.h」ファイルは下記フォルダのいずれかに配置すればいいはずです。

- C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32
- C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward
- C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1

「zlib.h」ファイルは「zlib.dll」をダウンロードしたときに一緒に含まれていました。
これを「C:\Ruby193\include\ruby-1.9.1」配下にコピーします。

再度コマンドプロンプトでxmindocをインストールしようとしましたが失敗しました。

```
>gem install xmindoc
（前のと同じエラー）
```

総当りで上記３フォルダすべてに「zlib.h」をコピーして試しました。
また、以下のフォルダにも「zlib.h」ファイルをコピーして試しましたが同様のエラーでした。

エラーログにあった「C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb」に関連するフォルダ

- 「C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe」があるフォルダ

  - C:/Ruby193/bin/
- 「extconf.rb」があるフォルダ配下

  - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2-x86-mingw32/ext/nokogiri/
  - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0.3.6/ext/

結果的に、以下の6箇所すべてに「zlib.h」ファイルをコピーして「>gem install xmindoc」しましたが同様のエラーでした。

- C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1
- C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32
- C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward
- C:/Ruby193/bin/
- C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2-x86-mingw32/ext/nokogiri/
- C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0.3.6/ext/

そもそも「conftest.c」ファイルが見当たりません。
「C:/Ruby193/」のサブフォルダを含めて検索したのですが。

## 手詰まり

ここで手がかりを失い、手詰まりになりました。
どうすればxmindocをインストールできるでしょうか？

初投稿ゆえ至らぬ点が多々あるかもしれませんが、
お力添えいただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

## 追記

### インストール成功

頂いたコメントにて解決いたしました。
無事、xmindocをインストールすることができました。
ありがとうございました。

```
C:\>gem uninstall zipruby1.9
Successfully uninstalled zipruby1.9-0.3.6-x86-mswin32

C:\>gem install zipruby1.9 --platform mswin32
Fetching: zipruby1.9-0.3.6-mswin32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed zipruby1.9-0.3.6-x86-mswin32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for zipruby1.9-0.3.6-x86-mswin32...
Installing RDoc documentation for zipruby1.9-0.3.6-x86-mswin32...

C:\>gem install nokogiri
Nokogiri is built with the packaged libraries: libxml2-2.9.2, libxslt-1.1.28, zl
ib-1.2.8, libiconv-1.14.
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.7.2-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.7.2-x86-mingw32...
unable to convert "\xE5" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to Wind
ows-31J for CHANGELOG.ja.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to Wind
ows-31J for CHANGELOG.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to Wind
ows-31J for ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.c, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for nokogiri-1.6.7.2-x86-mingw32...
unable to convert "\xE5" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to Wind
ows-31J for CHANGELOG.ja.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to Wind
ows-31J for CHANGELOG.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to Wind
ows-31J for ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.c, skipping

C:\>gem install xmindoc --ignore-dependencies
Fetching: xmindoc-0.0.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed xmindoc-0.0.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for xmindoc-0.0.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for xmindoc-0.0.7...
```

### xmindocが動作しない

さっそく実行してみましたが、xmindocが動作しませんでした。

インストールは成功しましたので、この質問は完了として別件で質問したいと思います。
[Windows XPでxmindocが動作しない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/26468/xmindoc%E3%81%8C%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-ruby-windowsxp)

Comment: 回答ではありませんが、自分もよくWindowsでgemのインストールに失敗した経験からコメントします。本当はWindows上ですっきりと動いたほうがいいのでしょうが、gemのインストールで build 関係のエラーが出てきた時は諦めてVirtualBoxもしくはそのラッパーのVagrantを使い、Linuxの仮想環境を構築してその中にインストールして使ったほうが環境構築の手間を差し引いてもストレスが少なく済みます。もしよければ試してみてください。

Comment: 貴重なアドバイスありがとうございます。
初めてのgem環境構築でしたので経験からのアドバイスとても助かります。

Windows上ではLinux仮想環境の中でgem環境を構築するのが一般的なのでしょうか。
ネットで調べてみてもそういう記事を見かけました。

じつはVirtualBoxを使ったことがあるのですがマシンスペックの都合上、起動だけでギリギリ稼動するという状態でした。PCのメモリが1GBしかなくメモリ不足で落ちてしまいます。

RubyをやるならまずPCやOSの環境から考え直さねばならないかもしれません…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

環境が無いため未検証ですが、インストールに失敗する zipruby は 1.9 用のバイナリが存在しますので、そちらをインストールすることで解決できないでしょうか？

1. zipruby の代わりに zipruby1.9 を入れます。

   ```
   gem install zipruby1.9 --platform mswin32
   ```
2. もう一つの依存関係にある nokogiri を個別で入れておきます。

   ```
   gem install nokogiri
   ```
3. 依存関係を無視して、xmindoc を入れます。

   ```
   gem install xmindoc --ignore-dependencies
   ```

下記も参考にしてください。

- http://d.hatena.ne.jp/lranran123/20130326/1364275938
- http://atsu23.jugem.jp/?eid=701
  ※ この記事にあるダウンロードのリンクは切れています。上で記載した [zipruby1.9 | RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/zipruby1.9) の Download からダウンロードしてください。

Comment: ご提示していただいた手順を試してみましたが、やはり同様のエラーがでてxmindocのインストールに失敗します。
zipruby1のインストールまではできました。「Successfully installed zipruby1.9-0.3.6-x86-mswin32」という表示をコマンドプロンプト上で確認しました。

Comment: 方法を少し変えてみましたので改めて確認してみてください。xmindocを普通に入れようとすると依存関係で本来のziprubyを見に行こうとして失敗するようです。なので、依存関係を無視して入れればいけるかも知れません。ダウンロードしたgemを入れている場合は、1.は実施しなくても大丈夫です。実施する場合は、`gem uninstall zipruby1.9`としてアンインストールしてから実施してください。

Comment: 新たにご提示していただいた手順でインストールに成功しました。
質問内容に追記しておきます。ありがとうございました。